# Proof using Cauchy Inequality.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

To prove $$(r_1+r_2+\cdots+r_n)^2\le n(r_1^2+r_2^2+\cdots+r_n^2) $$ for all $r_i$ in $\mathbb R$ and all $n\ge1$ , I get, using CI, $$|xy| \le\|x\|\|y\|= (r_1^2+r_2^2+\cdots+r_n^2)$$ But how do you generalize for $n\ge1$ and I feel that without orthogonality my equation is wrong.

Comment: Does it specifically ask you to use a cauchy inequality?

Comment: What are your $x$ and $y$? How are they related to $r_i$'s?

Answer (score 1):

The Cauchy Schwarz inequality says $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i ) \leq \|a\|\|b\|$ . Set $a_i =r_i,$ and $b_i =1$ for every $i.$ This implies the required inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = (1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ and $y = (r_1, r_2,\ldots,r_n)^T$. By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\vert x \cdot y \vert^2 \leq \|x\|^2 \|y\|^2$$
which is 
$$\left(1 \cdot r_1 + 1 \cdot r_2 + \ldots + 1 \cdot r_n \right)^2 \leq \left(1^2+ 1^2 + \ldots + 1^2 \right) \left(r_1^2 + r_2^2 + \ldots + r_n^2 \right)$$
and hence
$$\left(r_1+r_2+\ldots+ r_n\right)^2 \leq n \left(r_1^2 + r_2^2 + \ldots + r_n^2 \right)$$

Comment: Jeez, I was narrow minded, thanks a lot!